# Adding UI elements to a custom UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I'm trying to add some UI elements like `UIProgressView`, `UILabel`, `UIButton` and `UIActivityIndicator` - I think the code is correct (or so I thought), but nothing is showing except the background. What am I doing wrong?

```
@interface LoadingView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cancelButton;

- (void)removeLoadingView;

@end


@implementation LoadingView

@synthesize activityIndicator = _activityIndicator;
@synthesize progressView = _progressView;
@synthesize statusLabel = _statusLabel;
@synthesize cancelButton = _cancelButton;

- (UIView *)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34, 225, 248, 9)];
        self.statusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(36, 257, 248, 31)];
        self.cancelButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(121, 317, 74, 37)];

        // Create a new image view, from the image made by our gradient method
        UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self addBackground]];
        background.alpha = 0.8;
        [self addSubview:background];

        self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        // Set the resizing mask so it's not stretched
        self.activityIndicator.autoresizingMask =
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

        CGRect indicatorFrame = CGRectMake(142, 163, 37, 37);
        [self.activityIndicator setFrame:indicatorFrame];

        self.statusLabel.text = @"test 123";
        self.statusLabel.hidden = NO;
        self.statusLabel.enabled = YES;
        self.statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
        [self addSubview:self.progressView];
        [self addSubview:self.cancelButton];
        [self addSubview:self.statusLabel];

        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

       /* // Create a new animation
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        // Set the type to a nice wee fade
        [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
        // Add it to the superView
        [[super layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"layerAnimation"];*/

    }
    return self;
}



- (UIImage *)addBackground{
    // Create an image context (think of this as a canvas for our masterpiece) the same size as the view
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 1);
    // Our gradient only has two locations - start and finish. More complex gradients might have more colours
    size_t num_locations = 2;
    // The location of the colors is at the start and end
    CGFloat locations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    // These are the colors! That's two RBGA values
    CGFloat components[8] = {
        0.4,0.4,0.4, 0.8,
        0.1,0.1,0.1, 0.5 };
    // Create a color space
    CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    // Create a gradient with the values we've set up
    CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);
    // Set the radius to a nice size, 80% of the width. You can adjust this
    float myRadius = (self.bounds.size.width*.8)/2;
    // Now we draw the gradient into the context. Think painting onto the canvas
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myGradient, self.center, 0, self.center, myRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    // Rip the 'canvas' into a UIImage object
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // And release memory
    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);
    CGGradientRelease(myGradient);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    // … obvious.
    return image;
}
```

EDIT: so I just put the code in `viewDidload` and nothing shows now, not even the background. I've also tried the code in `layoutSubviews` and same results as the code above, everything except the background is hidden.

The code I am using to instantiate this view from a view controller is;

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LoadingView *loadingView;

@synthesize loadingView = _loadingView;

- (LoadingView *)loadingView
{
    if (!_loadingView) _loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    return _loadingView;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
}
```

Comment: can u show d code, why u r calling this mthd and adding on the subview..

Comment: i tried the same code, added on the view successfully.. how u r accessing this view controller, by pushing/presenting... because while alloc a controller viewDidLoad is called, & while push/present other view cycle mthds will be called..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only after posting the code for the `@interface` did I realise I was creating the elements with a `weak` pointer. I changed it to `strong` and everything shows up fine. Thanks everyone for the answers, I know I confused you all by not showing the entire code.

Comment: Good to know that you sorted it.

Answer (score 3):

Put this into `viewDidLoad` of your view controller. This will ensure that your main view is already there.

Comment: Just tried putting the code in `viewDidLoad` and nothing shows up, not even the background...so weird.

Comment: To be sure @Mundi mentioned to put the code into `viewDidLoad`. Doing so, take the code snippet between the if statement from the `initWithFrame` method and paste it into `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you call the method `initWithFrame:` in the place you want?

I think you'd better add the code in method `init:` or `-ViewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1):

Try self.cancelButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; and see if anything shows up.

Custom buttons created with code by default have no background image or colour, you need to manually specify them.

Answer (score 1):

You should do that in `viewDidLoad`, or in `- (void)layoutSubviews` if you're building a custom UIView

Comment: When I put the code in `viewDidLoad` nothing shows up, not even the background, when I put it in `layoutSubviews` it's the same as the code above, nothing shows except the background.

Answer (score 1):

Should you not be adding the new UI Elements to the view of self and not to just self. So it would look a little something like this :

```
 [[self view] addSubview:background];
```

and not

```
 [self addSubview:background];
```

***edit***

Try this see all the views on the controller.

```
    for(UIView *vw in self.subviews) {
         NSLog(@"View : %@", vw);
    }
```

If you can't access self.subviews this means that you can't add any views except for the initial view so you have to start adding to the [self view]. Try changing the self.subviews to [[self view] subviews];

Your background view could have been placed as the initial view as it is a UIImageView, try adding to that.

Comment: Well it's a custom UIView, so I want to add the subViews to itself. Plus doesn't explain why the background shows but no other elements show.

Comment: there is no `[self view]` the code is within a `UIView` subclass not a `UIViewController` - i've tried adding `NSLog(@"%@", self.subviews)` at the bottom of the `initWithFrame` method and the only thing that shows is the background. So I tried `[background addSubview:self.activityIndicator]` and still nothing shows up.

Comment: Also when I remove `[self addSubview:background]` the next item to be added to the subview doesn't show, nor is it within `self.subviews`

Comment: The only thing I can think of then is to only create your view (Your background view in your case) and then after that has been added in your viewDidload start adding everything else then. Please let us know if you resolve this as I am interested. +1 to your question.

Comment: I'm a dummy, there was nothing wrong with the code I posted, it was something wrong with the code I didn't post. I was assigning the UI elements with a weak point and that's why they didn't show. See my answer. I have +1 everyones answer for helping :)